# Seemingly redundant of onomatopoeia

Tags: grammar

> まぶたを**しぱしぱと何度も**瞬かせました。

This feels reduntant, my dictionary says that しぱしぱ is the sound of blinking repeatedly, but doesnt already 瞬かせる(to blink) 何度も (many times) do its work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

しぱしぱ is an onomatopoeia that can be used when blinking at least twice. 何度も means blinking many times, say, more than five. So adding 何度も does have a meaning here, and this phrase is not redundant. Likewise, コンコンとドアをノックする is like "knock knock", and コンコンと何回もドアをノックする is like "knock knock knock knock...".